# Max pool layer vs Convolution with stride performance

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

In most of the architectures, conv layers are being followed by a pooling layer (max / avg etc.). As those pooling layers are just selecting the output of previous layer (i.e. conv), can we just use convolution with stride 2 and expect the similar accuracy results with reduced process need?

Comment: Ya I have tried it vgg19 network and it works

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes that can be done. Its explained in the paper `'Striving for simplicity: The all convolutional net'` https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6806.pdf. Quote from the paper:

> 'We find that max-pooling can simply be replaced by a convolutional
>   layer with increased stride without loss in accuracy  on several image
>   recognition benchmarks'

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, why industry is keeping using max-pools?